# How can I access request headers that don't appear in $_SERVER?

Tags: php, http, http-headers

I am attempting to create a REST API in PHP and I'd like to implement an authentication scheme similar to Amazon's S3 approach. This involves setting a custom 'Authorization' header in the request.

I had thought I would be able to access the header with $_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'], but it's nowhere to be found in var_dump($_SERVER). The apache_request_headers() function would solve my problem, but my host implements PHP as CGI, so it's unavailable.

Is there another way I can access the complete request headers in PHP?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You'll need to do some `mod_rewrite` wizardry to get your headers past the CGI barrier, like so:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule .? - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

<?php
    $auth = $_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'];
?>
```

Note that if you're using `mod_rewrite` for other purposes, it could end up being `$_SERVER['REDIRECT_HTTP_AUTHORIZATION']`.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
$_ENV['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION']
```

When using CGI interface instead of Apache Module interface, HTTP headers should be available as environment variables.

Answer (score 1):

There is a fantastic PECL extension that allows for all sorts of HTTP related access. [PECL_HTTP](http://pecl.php.net/package/pecl_http) and more specifically http://php.net/http and http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-get-request-headers.php.