# How to process a Authentication Header with PHP

Tags: php, api, http, http-headers, basic-authentication

I've to develop a API interface that recives a POST with JSON content and process it.
To be safe, it has to accept only a valid token.

The software that connect to my API send a Auth header with "Basic 134asSdsw324bvv3w4tvc45==" content.

My  problem is  to have my PHP script to process that token... In apache_request_headers() there is no Authentication header, neither on my $_SERVER variable...

Any sugestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you certain it actually sends the header? Not meant to be condescending but just ruling out possibilities.

Comment: Pretty sure it is, I don't have access to the code, but it say it does... :(

Comment: Do you run PHP as CGI? If so check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/827060/how-can-i-access-request-headers-that-dont-appear-in-server?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of CGI being striping out the authentication header, I had to add this to my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule .? - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

<?php
    $auth = $_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'];
?>
```

Full answer: [How can I access request headers that don't appear in $_SERVER?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/827060/how-can-i-access-request-headers-that-dont-appear-in-server?rq=1)